# Dynamic SQL query - > row data to column name

Tags: php, mysql, pivot

I have a little/big problem with dynamic SQL query/ row datas to column name.
I have this link:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4478/1

But if i adding VERY more  datas, the query not working.
I getting error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM test
 GROUP  BY nid' at line 2
```

my database is big currently.
in the next days i making the empty database.
i adding to names(another table, connected id to "nid"), date(datum), amount(osszeg).
week to week the data is too much(maybe but once too much, and then not working the query)

and i need a simple/single PHP query code for this query.

Thanks for helping and sorry my bad english.
Very thanks!

Comment: Could you post the statement that is causing the error?  With VERY?

Comment: You may be running into a limit on the number of columns you can select.

Comment: There could also be an issue with the result returned from `GROUP_CONCAT()`; it has a limit (default 1024 characters).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual SQL statement, we're just guessing. But I suspect that you are running into documented behavior of the `GROUP_CONCAT` function, which returns a string of maximum length specified by the MySQL variable `GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN`. The default is 1024 bytes.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 1024;
```

For debugging, you could have the MySQL stored program to emit the contents of `@sql`, instead of attempting to prepared it, e.g.

```
SELECT @sql;
```

You may want to consider comparing the length (in bytes) of the string returned from the `GROUP_CONCAT` function is not equal to the maximum length `GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN`, to check whether the value has been truncated.

---

On a different note, I would opt for returning this result as a set of rows, rather than as columns on a single row. And I would do any required translation for display on the client side, rather than doing it in the database.